# TextView is not updated within RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, textview

I'm developing a custom camera app. CameraPreview takes a part of the screen, and the rest of the screen on the rightis allocated for control panel.

Now, when I change the shooting parameters, the text view and toggle views on the control panels are not updated. I guess this is because of the camera, but I have no clue what to do.

This is a screen shot:

[the screen shot with messed textview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2G8EqxP3VAaamFQczhLU2x2WUk/edit?usp=sharing)

My layout looks like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/total_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/gen_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#AA8888">


  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </FrameLayout>


   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >





        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topLeftMark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/red_left_top_corner"
            android:tag="mark" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bottomLeftMark"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/red_left_bottom_corner"
                    android:tag="mark" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/topRightMark"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/red_right_top_corner"
                    android:tag="mark" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bottomRightMark"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/red_right_bottom_corner"
                    android:tag="mark" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/leftCrop"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/rect_60_trasparent" />

                 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rightCrop"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/rect_60_trasparent" />

                 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/upperCrop"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/rect_60_trasparent" />


                  <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bottomCrop"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/rect_60_trasparent" />

        </RelativeLayout>



   </FrameLayout> <!--  GEN_VIEW END -->

          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/whparent"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <include layout="@layout/wheel_panel"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

              <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/adLayout"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:gravity="bottom" 
              android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/whparent"
              android:layout_alignTop="@id/whparent"
              >

            </RelativeLayout>

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/whparent"

            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/hello"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/control_panel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Pocket Viewfinder" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewAngle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="@string/hello"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widerWarning"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="@string/wWarning"
                android:textColor="@color/warning_color"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_capture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="@string/capture_button" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/booster_toggle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textOff="@string/booster_off"
                android:textOn="@string/booster_on" />


        </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout> <!--  TOTAL_VIEW END -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everytime the TextView text is changed, I call:

```
controlPanelView.requestLayout();
```

But the controlPanelView is not updated at all.

What am I doing wrong? THNX

Comment: Something is missing in the code above: the "Capture" button is not there. Update the question with the correct XML please.

Comment: Initially I posted shortened xml, now it is full.